# Win-V and Win-dot hotkeys no longer working

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Sometime in the last few weeks, without any change on my side the hotkeys for the emoji panel and the clipboard history have stopped working.

I've made sure both features are enabled and sticky keys are off. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Is Win+; working?

Comment: No, that one is not working either :(